# Azure SQL Server slow to open connection

Tags: azure

After migrating one of our websites that uses Umbraco CMS (v6.2.6) from on-premise web and database servers into Azure, there have been huge performance implications for users in the back-office.  I have tried scaling up the resources but this is not the issue as the DTU utilization only maxes out at 35%, even when bursting / spiking is seen.  The SQL server is S0 standard service tier (10 DTU's) and the resource group that it sits in is S3 standard service tier (4 core / 7gb) - located US East.

I duplicated the azure app service and sql database and attached an instance of New Relic to it in Azure and the findings are a bit disturbing.

[Call Trace #1 - 77% of the time is spent opening SqlConnections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcax2.png)

If it makes any difference, I ran the same code / tests locally with a local instance of SQL server and the response times were much quicker - with little to no time being used to open the connection - [Localhost StackifyPrefix Trace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Aks.png) I didn't write the data-layer code so adjusting it at this point is definitely out of the question, as cringe-worthy as it may seem...is there anything else that can be done to mitigate this?  That seems like an absurdly long time to just open the SQL connection a bunch of times

Comment: Sorry for the mandatory question, but are these resources on the same datacenter?

Comment: @BrunoFaria Not a problem - Yes they are all in the East US, Virginia datacenter

Comment: Very strange indeed. Can you try another datacenter? I work with Azure for at least 5 years now and East US is simply unreliable. I don't use it for production anymore. Try East Us 2. About 2 days ago SQL database was having problems on this DC.

Comment: Did you use `Server=YourServer.database.windows.net` or `Server=tcp:YourServer.database.windows.net,1433` in the connection string?

Comment: @GregGalloway I use the latter, `Server=tcp:YourServer.database.windows.net,1433`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix to this was in the connection string - in June of 2016, the Azure SQL Database portal showed this as their copy and paste connection string for ADO.NET

`Server=tcp:{your db resource group name},1433;Initial Catalog={your db instance};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;`

At some point in the last 4 or 5 months, they removed `Pooling=False` from their connection string examples in ADO.NET but at this point I had just copied and pasted the connection string from one site into another because it already had the db creds / resource group names and all I had to do was change the actual catalog that it pointed to.

When Pooling=False is set, each time a connection is called with `Close()` or `Dispose()` in .NET, the connection is actually closed instead of being returned to the connection pool for later use.  When a new connection is needed, the TCP 3-way handshake and communication between the client and database server must be established which can have big performance impacts on sites with lots of queries.  By removing `Pooling=False` from the connection string, connection pooling functionality is automatically enabled by default with ADO.NET.

Comment: I don't have `Pooling=False` in my connection string and the first time that the app web connects to the sql server it is really slow...